# how to add a custom link on top menu of sonata admin symfony2

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

First I am new in Symfony2, I develop a project by using Symfony2 with SonataAdminBundle, everything is well but I don't know how to add a custom link in top menu without entity.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `standard_layout.html.twig` by creating a custom admin bundle and place that file in exact the same folder structure. If you open up the original `standard_layout.html.twig` you can see that it has following block in it `{% block top_bar_before_nav %} {% endblock %}`. That's the one you want to put your own menu item in. Here is some more info about [templating](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html) the SonataAdminBundle.

Comment: Given you have have _registered_ the `SonataAdminBundle`, you can **override** whatever block you need to by `{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}` in your custom template. 
If don't want to override but **add** to the block, put `{{ parent() }}` before your customization code. (Tested for Symfony 3.)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        user_block: YOURBUNDLE:<optional Directory>:Twig-template
```

That's for sonata admin bundle :( dev-master. Kind of 2.2.x

The template is warpped by an ul-tag, so use li's:

```
<li>First User message</li>
```

A helpful console-command is

```
php app/console config:debug sonata_admin
```